# PHP: Scripting (XSS_in_URI.script)

Tags: php, security, xss

When I check my script with Acunetix vuln scanner i see this `XSS` error :

```
This vulnerability affects /cms/search.php. 
Discovered by: Scripting (XSS_in_URI.script). 

Attack details
URI was set to "onmouseover='prompt(961413)'bad=">
The input is reflected inside a tag parameter between double quotes.
```

in `search.php` page i safe all user input with this:(safeXSS name of anti XSS function)

```
if (isset($_POST['search'])) { 
  $search = array_map ('safeXSS', $_POST);
 }
else
 {
  $search = array_map ('rawurldecode', $_GET);
  $search = array_map ('safeXSS', $search);
 }
```

search form input:

```
<input type="submit" name="search"  class="submit" value="search" />
```

I do not understand what's my problem?! how do i can fix this?

Comment: Can you post the parameter in wich it show the alert?.Normally this means you haven't quoted the markup, but at a guess I'd say you have a poorly-formed input tag for your "username" input. For instance, perhaps it's missing the closing " on the value attribute, and the text you see quoted is what follows it. But I can not see that problem on the input you show, are you sure is about that input ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your PHP template somewhere you will have code like:

```
<a href="<?php echo $uri ?>">
```

or:

```
echo "<a href=\"$uri\">";
```

HTML-escaping is missing here, so if a quote character is included in the value in `$uri` then that URI content escapes the attribute value it is supposed to be contained in, and you get dangerous output:

```
<a href=""onmouseover='prompt(961413)'bad=">">
```

You should fix this by calling `htmlspecalchars()` each and every time you output a plain text string into HTML text content or attribute values:

```
<a href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($uri, ENT_QUOTES 'utf-8') ?>">
```

(You can make this less obtrusive by defining a short-named function like `h()` that calls `echo htmlspecialchars` for you. Or, in the longer term, prefer to use a template language that does this automatically for you.)

The filtering you've got on `$_POST`/`$_GET` is not at all effective. It is unclear what `safeXSS` is doing exactly, and I have absolutely no idea what `rawurldecode` is there for, but in general it is not possible to implement correct handling of string escaping at the input stage.

Using input ‘sanitisation’ to attempt to combat XSS is a common antipattern that should be avoided. (You may want to do custom input filtering for other reasons, but it's the wrong way to handle injection/escaping problems.) HTML-injection, JavaScript-injection, XML-injection and so on are output-stage concerns; the input stage doesn't know what contexts input is going to be used in yet, so can't treat the input in the correct way for that output context.